# Python - take each n-th element (in place)

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
a = a[::3]
b = b[::3]
c = c[::3]
d = d[::3]
```

`a,b,c,d,` are actually pretty complicated expressions, so I want to write it like this:

```
for l in [a, b, c, d]
    l = l[::3]
```

, but of course it doesn't work.
How can I take each n-th element in place? If it was about deleting each n-th element, I could use `del`, but it's not.

Essentially, I want to:

- Use each of `a,b,c,d` only once
- Specify slicing (or whatever) only once.

Comment: You can assign to `l` in-place.

    `for l in [a, b, c, d]: l[:] = l[::3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current approach, by doing `l = l[::3]` you are just reassigning the variable, or in other words, creating a copy of the list, which will leave `a` unchanged.

Lets check with an example, where by using `id` we can see that the identity of the objects is different after the reassignment:

```
for i in [a,b]:
    print(id(a)) # 43269876104
    print(id(i)) # 43269876104
    i = i[::3]
    print(id(i)) # 43271280456
    break
```

However, you can modify the data in place with a *slice-assignment*:

```
for i in [a,b]:
    print(id(a)) # 43269876104
    print(id(i)) # 43269876104
    i[:] = i[::3]
    print(id(i)) # 43269876104
    break
```

---

So going back to you're case you could do:

```
for i in [a, b, c, d]:
    i[:] = i[::3]
```

---

Here's a simple example:

```
a = list(range(30))
b = list(range(30))

for i in [a,b]:
    i[:] = i[::3]

print(b)
# [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
```

Comment: Thanks! It's so simple, I'm ashamed.

Comment: Not sure how `for i in [a,b]:` works, could you explain @yatu ?

Comment: Sure, added an explantion @DeveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a list comprehension with tuple unpacking:

```
a, b, c, d = [l[::3] for l in (a, b, c, d)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question to say why exactly this solution doesn't work for me.